# Create SQL Server SSL

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, sql-server-2017, windows-server-2016

I want to create a SQL Server SSL certificate on my Windows Server 2016, and I followed the steps shown in this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7ONeACYBdE&t=182s

In the video the presenter publish this PowerShell line:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName host.doman.com -KeySpec KeyExchange -FriendlyName SQLCer
```

Unfortunately the presenter didn't explain whether something should be changed in this line or whether it is generic, so when I use it on my PowerShell, it create the certificate but in the next step, when I need to select it in the Protocols Window (in the configuration Manager), the certificate in the "drop down" list is empty.

[image]

I used the PowerShell line exactly as I wrote it above, do I need change something in this line ? Is the certificate missing because of that or it's something else ?

Comment: This should really be on [sf] now that I think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question of the part to be modified, you need to change the "DnsName" host.doman.com and replace it with your dns name

According to SQL Server SSL certificate please check the following URL for the steps

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b29f5e8-67fc-40d1-9bde-1521cbdfe07e/sql-server-2008-ssl-certificate-list-blank?forum=sqlgetstarted

Comment: thank you, the DnsName should be "full computer name" no suffix needed.

Comment: Sorry, i meant DNSName, i modified it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

In that Powershell statement, you should modify it with the DNS name, and also add in "Server Authentication" extension, as follows:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate `
  -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My `
  -DnsName YOURSERVERADDRESSHERE `
  -KeySpec KeyExchange `
  -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") `
  -FriendlyName SQLCer
```

where `YOURSERVERADDRESSHERE` is the address used to connect to your server, such as `SqlServer.MyDomain.com`.

---

Even after this, you may not see the certificate in the drop-down. Instead you can manually insert it into the registry.

In Powershell, execute `$cert.Thumprint`.

Then take that value and insert it as a value at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<YourSQLServerInstance>\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib` in a key named `Certificate`.